# How can I write entire rows into an Armadillo matrix?

Tags: c++, armadillo

In Armadillo I want to save many row vectors into a matrix. I can change an entry of a matrix A with:

```
arma:mat A(10,10, 0); // create a 10x10 matrix filled with zeros.
A(i,j) = 1.23; // set element at positon (i,j) to 1.23.
```

Is there a way of changing an entire row of the matrix at once? e.g.:

```
arma::rowvec V(10); // a row vector of length 10.
A(i) = V; //write entire rowvector V into matrix at position i.
```

I know I can use
    A.insert_rows(i, V);
to insert my Vector V into the matrix, but I want to replace it. In my code I already know the dimensions of my matrix. I could also append the rows at the and, but I read somewhere that the code runs faster, if I don't change the size of the matrix and instead initialize it with the right size.
If anyone's interested I am writing a programm that is solving differential equations and I need to write the system state (a vector) into an array (an Armadillo Matrix) in order to save the timeseries.

I thought I could use armadillo matrices, because my system state is an armadillo vector. I looked around in Armadillo's documentation but I cannot find a proper way to to this. (Proper meaning anything other than writing a loop that iterates over all entries of my vector - I know C++ is doing something like this internally, but my guess is that using armadillo functions would be faster).

Answer (score 4):

Use [submatrix views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat). Some examples:

```
arma::mat A(10,10, arma::fill::zeros);
arma::rowvec V(10, arma::fill::randu);

A.row(2) = V;
A.row(3).ones();
A.row(4).randu();
A.row(5).fill(123.4);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That has been very _very_ helpful! It's actually so obvious when I think about it now. I probably didn't understand the documentation...